# PHP: Number of consecutive elements in array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have been working on one problem:

Find the largest group of consecutive numbers in an array.

Say we have an array `[5, 43, 4, 56, 3, 2, 44, 57, 58, 1]`, the biggest group of consecutive numbers in this array is 5 (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5).

The solution algorithm must be time complexity of O(n).

I have solved this with the following ruby code but I am having trouble porting it to PHP as the solution requires.

```
arr = [8, 13, 14, 10, 6, 7, 8, 14, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4]
result = []
stage = []
for i in arr:
    if len(stage) > 0 and i != stage[-1]+1:
        if len(stage) > 1:
            result.append(stage)
        stage = []
    stage.append(i)
print result
```

Comment: a/ your code does not do what your description says. b/ complexity of o(n) for what you describe i not possible. (I don't have a formal proof of that, but I don't see how it could be possible so far) (actually, it may be possible)

Comment: i would also add asort of array in beginning to get array number ascending. And on the end i would have result array of numbers > and checked for biggest array in result

Comment: if you sort the elements, you'll have duplicates and your complexity jumps to o(nlogn)

Comment: too broad does not quite cut it. I said unclear, because of the difference between the description and the code. (no need to shout, though).

Comment: @JohnConde I would like to provide an answer to this question.  What needs to happen to re-open?  Does this question need a specific edit?

Comment: hey @mickmackusa question was closed, because being to broad. If you wish you are free to use the comments. If you wish to participate.

Comment: @NejcRodošek Using comments to answer is not good SO citizenship.  I want to know what needs to be satisfied to reopen / make it less broad.  Honestly, I think this is a poor rationale for closure on this question (and moderators may have been a bit too trigger happy on the day, and I probably would have responded with the capslock on too).  Then again, I am looking at MikeLyons' edit, perhaps your initial post was too unclear.  Regardless, I would like to see this question re-opened.

Comment: @njzk2 could you consider voting to re-open this question? or explaining what needs to happen for it to qualify for re-opening?

Comment: @Rizier123 could you consider voting to re-open this question? or explaining what needs to happen for it to qualify for re-opening?

Comment: @LyzandeR could you consider voting to re-open this question? or explaining what needs to happen for it to qualify for re-opening?

Comment: @NejcRodošek I have just gained the privilege to cast a re-open vote (Yeah!).  I would like to see this question re-opened, but I think the sticking point is the fact that you are requiring O(n).  Is this something you can remove as a requirement?  Please take a moment to review/refine your question, then ping me and I'll consider requesting a re-open.

Comment: This question looks like a codewars or hackreactor test.  I think the user was having stack solve the issue..  Hmm, if thats the case, stack isnt here to solve complete problems, its easier to learn by asking specific questions, which is why it was flagged as too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = [8, 13, 14, 10, 6, 7, 8, 14, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4];

$res = [];
$stage = [];

foreach($a as $i) {
    if(count($stage) > 0 && $i != $stage[count($stage)-1]+1) {
        if(count($stage) > 1) {
            $res[] = $stage;
        }
        $stage = [];
    }
    $stage[] = $i;

}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Well actually it's pure php without ruby. If you are confused with an array declaration as [], do not be, because: As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []. And my code does exactly the same that yours ruby does. But about algorithm you're right, it is still not the solution.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this. Now i tested it with 5.4 version and works. now i just have to tweek it a bit

Comment: This solution works fine for single digit consecutive numbers only. Try with the following array:

$a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15];

Ideally it should return 9,10,11,12 also but it will NOT, whereas it will only return 1,2,3 because these are single digits.

Comment: this does not return the OP's expected result for their input. (but apparently there is confusion to what "consecutive" means)

Answer (score 5):

It's not O(n) but you can try this:

```
// Define array
$array = array(5,8,3,2,10,11,15,13,12,1,4,5,16);

// Sorting
asort($array);

$previous = null; 
$result = array();
$consecutiveArray = array();

// Slice array by consecutive sequences
foreach($array as $number) {
    if ($number == $previous + 1) {
        $consecutiveArray[] = $number;
    } else {
        $result[] = $consecutiveArray;
        $consecutiveArray = array($number);
    }
    $previous = $number;
}
$result[] = $consecutiveArray;

// Get length of each sub array
$count = array_map('count', $result);
```

You can get max length by `max($count)`.

This solution gives you following array:

```
array(
    0 => array(1,2,3,4,5)
    1 => array(5)
    2 => array(8)
    3 => array(10,11,12,13)
    4 => array(15,16)
```

Comment: what is time complexity then? O(nLogn)?

Comment: It depends on sorting function. If you provide sorted array then you can omit sorting and get O(n).

Comment: sorting function must be in algorithm. i would sort it with sort() or asort if it has less time complexity. so what is complexity of asort O(1)?

Comment: the issue with this code is that it does not account for duplicate values.

Comment: It worked fine in my case as I don't have any duplicates in my array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python (my PHP is not too good) that does what your description asks, in o(n) if your sequence is decreasing:

```
lists = dict()
for i in val:
    if i in lists:
        continue
    a = {i}
    if (i + 1) in lists:
        b = lists[i+1]
        b.update(a)
        a = b
    if (i - 1) in lists:
        b = lists[i-1]
        # this messes up the complexity
        for k in b:
            lists[k] = a
        a.update(b)
    lists[i] = a
```

The idea is that `lists` maintain a dict of sets indexed on *all* the elements in the list. Whenever you encounter a new element, the previous and next sets are merged, if present.

The `update` operation is technically `o(n)`, but it is not compounded by the external loop, as there can only be `n` insertion into sets by merging. The overall is `o(n)`

If the sequence is not sorted, the merge of the +1 and -1 sets gives a not-so-good complexity.