# count elements consecutive array php

Tags: php

I have the array:

```
$type = ['A','A','A','E','E','E','A','E','A','A','E','E'];
          1   2   3                       4   5
```

And I intend to count the number of elements `A` that are included in consecutive chains with length more or equal 2. In the example I have three chains but i want count only two of them. Altogether result should be 5.

Comment: And what about 7 => 'CA', ?

Comment: Try this = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300833/searching-for-consecutive-values-in-an-array

Comment: Or this one = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614124/php-number-of-consecutive-elements-in-array

Comment: CA - It is an element of the array

Comment: Have you tried something? Show some code.

Comment: @Rizier123 unhold this question. I've edited it. But reputation is not enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find consecutive chains of 'CA"

```
$count = 0;
$link = array();                     // Here will be chain lengths

array_push($types, '');              // to work if the last item == 'CA'

foreach($types as $item) 
  if ($item == 'CA') $count++;       
  else if ($count) 
         { $link[] = $count; $count = 0; }  

rsort($link);                        // 3, 2, 1
$sum = 0;
foreach ($link as $i) 
   if ($i >= 2) $sum += $i;          // Count result
   else break;                       // Further chains are shorter than we want

echo $sum;
```